# How to troubleshoot empty /var/log/secure /var/log/messages etc log on linux

Tags: linux, centos7, syslog, rsyslog

Today(2016-12-14), i login my vps and `cat /var/log/secure` `/var/log/messages`, but all these log files are empty except `*-20161211`. I don't know what happen. How to fix it? I need help, thanks!

Here is my screenshot.
[image: empty secure and fail2ban]

When i `cat /var/log/fail2ban-20161211` it shows, but secure log was end up by 2016-12-08
[image]

Here is my config
[image]

rsyslog is also running.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, i solve it.
Just add the code in config

```
/bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/rsyslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` || true
```

After i restart the server, it works.

Comment: This didn't work for me. There is already a line simular to that in the config too?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I had a similar problem and it worked for me.

Check if you have this line in /etc/rsyslog file:
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none /var/log/messages

if you have, remove the "*":
.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none /var/log/messages

restart the rsyslog and check if the file has been upgraded.